# How to retrieve n-th to last block information?

Tags: node

Using the tezos-client is there a command to retrieve information about the n-th to last block ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
 ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head~100
```

This will display the block 100 prior to the current head.